# How to relate toric data and group character?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory

If I collect the Cartan generators of su(3) or sl(3,C), then the diagonal entries   can be arranged as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1& -2 \\\
0& 1 &-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

after a row operation this becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1\\\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is the toric data of $CP^2$. I can then write the semigroup action/coordinate ring through the characters.

In fact, this generalizes to show the connection between $SU(n+1)$   and $CP^n$.

Now, how to relate this character to the character of repersentation of the group? this should be related to the highest weight rep.